# In React, failing to stop Axios request when component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, axios

With data fetching in React, the following is a common warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. in ParentComponent

I've read multiple posts and suggestions on how to handle this, and none are working currently.

For this, we have the function `useAxiosApi` which fetches data asynchronously, and `ParentComponent` which is the component that uses the `useAxiosApi()` and needs the data. `ParentComponent` is the component being unmounted / being referenced in the warnings.

**Parent Component**

```
import useAxiosApi...
function ParentComponent({ info }) {
    const dataConfig = { season: info.season, scope: info.scope };
    const [data, isLoading1, isError1] = useAxiosApi('this-endpoint', [], dataConfig);

    return (
        {isLoading && <p>We are loading...</p>}
        {!isLoading &&
            ... use the data to render something...
        }
    )
}
```

**useAxiosApi**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import useDeepCompareEffect from 'use-deep-compare-effect';

const resources = {};
const useAxiosApi = (endpoint, initialValue, config) => {
    // Set Data-Fetching State
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    // Use in lieu of useEffect
    useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
        // Token/Source should be created before "fetchData"
        let source = axios.CancelToken.source();
        let isMounted = true;

        // Create Function that makes Axios requests
        const fetchData = async () => {
            // For Live Search on keystroke, Save Fetches and Skip Fetch if Already Made
            if (endpoint === 'liveSearch' && resources[config.searchText]) {
                return [resources[config.searchText], false, false];
            }

            // Otherwise, Continue Forward
            setIsError(false);
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const url = createUrl(endpoint, config);
                const result = await axios.get(url, { cancelToken: source.token });

                console.log('isMounted: ', isMounted);
                if (isMounted) {
                    setData(result.data);
                }

                // If LiveSearch, store the response to "resources"
                if (endpoint === 'liveSearch') {
                    resources[config.searchText] = result.data;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setIsError(true);
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        // Call Function
        fetchData();

        // Cancel Request if needed in cleanup function
        return () => {
            console.log('Unmount or New Search? About to call source.cancel()');
            isMounted = false; // is this doing its job?
            source.cancel();
        };
    }, [endpoint, config]);

    // Return as length-3 array
    return [data, isLoading, isError];
};

export default useAxiosApi;
```

`createUrl` is simply a function that takes the `endpoint` and `dataConfig` and creates the url that axios will fetch from. Note that our cancelTokens seem to be working in conjunction with the Live search, as new searches are cancelling the old search queries, and the saving of data results into `resources` for the one specific endpoint `liveSearch` works as well.

However, our problem is that when `ParentComponent` is unmounted quickly, before the data fetch is complete, we still receive the `Cant perform a React state update` warning. I've checked the `console.logs()`, and `console.log('isMounted: ', isMounted)` is **always returning true**, even if we unmount the component quickly after it is mounted / before data fetching is complete.

We're at a loss on this, as using the `isMounted` variable is the way that I've seen this problem handled before. Perhaps there's a problem with the `useDeepCompareEffect` hook? Or maybe we're missing something else.

**Edit:** Weve also tried to create the `isMounted` variable from inside of `ParentComponent`, and pass that as a parameter into the `useAxiosApi` function, however this did not work for us either... In general, it would be much better if we can handle this warning via an update to our `useAxiosApi` function, as opposed to in the `ParentComponent`.

**Edit2:** It seems like the `cancelToken` only works when a duplicate API call is fired off to the same endpoint. This is good for our liveSearch, however it means that all of the other fetches are not cancelled.

Comment: Two things I can think of: 1. Because of alot of your state updates happen in `fetchData()`, can you place that within an `if` statement in the `useDeepCompareEffect`? Say, `if (isMounted) { fetchData() }`. What happens when you try that? 2. Did you try including the `AbortController()` function? It can sometimes be effective especially if working with `async` calls.

Comment: Perhaps. I will look into each of these. I have not tried the `AbortController()`, only the `cancelTokens` and the `isMounted`. Thank you for the sugestions.